# GTest on iOS with Xcode 7.3/8

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, googletest, xctest

Can anyone please give me any clear instruction on how to use googletest
/GTest framework on iOS platform(On actual iOS app) ? And how to integrate it with XCTest framework for reporting ?

I have tried but with no success and also there is not enough resource on this topic. Below is the links for reference.

https://github.com/google/googletest

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googletestframework/v7P0sqQ3Y3c

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get it to fully work the same as XCTest in Xcode, but you can get some of the functionality by adding a file [1] that loops thru all your GTest-tests and adds them as XCTest-tests. See more info at [2].

Basically:

1. Create a test target in Xcode
2. Add all Gtest source files to the test target
3. Add the file [1] to the test target
4. Run the tests

[1] https://github.com/mattstevens/xcode-googletest/blob/master/Bundle/GoogleTests.mm

[2] https://github.com/mattstevens/xcode-googletest